# Film with metal base/city and spaceships in canyon landscape

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone recognise this film?

[image]

It plays for a second or less in a montage of films available for streaming on TVNZ+, but I have searched through their catalog and not been able to identify it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [reverse Google image search](https://mossfilm.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/after-earth-film-review/) says that it is [After Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1815862/). The city in the image is [Nova Prime City](https://afterearth.fandom.com/wiki/Nova_Prime_City)

> One thousand years in the future, humanity has abandoned Earth and resettled on     a distant planet called Nova Prime where aliens known as the S’krell use large predatory creatures called Ursa to hunt down humans they feel have invaded their territory. When fifteen-year-old cadet Kitai Raige (Jaden Smith) and his career officer father Cypher (Will Smith) crashland on Earth – what begins as an opportunity for a father/son bonding session – quickly becomes a rite of passage for young Kitai – as he is forced to learn to control his fear in the face of a terrifying alien adversary.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Google could search for photos of a TV screen, I thought it was just for exact images matches, finding duplicates etc. After Earth is in their catalog and featured again in the montage, but I thought it was all jungles and such.

Comment: I've seen After Earth and to be fair about 80% of the film is set in jungles and not this city, it's not significant in the story as far as I can remember as well.